# Decoding JSON into an array for a xbox live image script?

Tags: php, json, decode, xbox

I'm trying to turn a `JSON` file of Xbox Live data into variables that I can use in a `PHP` generated image. My JSON file is here: http://www.xboxgamercard.org/gamercard/test3/xbox.php

I have tried this:

```
$request_url = 'xbox.php';
$json = file_get_contents($request_url);
$decode = json_decode($json, true);
var_dump($decode['gamertag'][0]);
```

but it just returns `NULL`.

I would like to use the JSON as shown here:

```
$gamertag = $data['Gamertag'];
echo $gamertag;
```

Comment: you don't have any element `$decode['gamertag'][0]`. Do a `var_dump($decode)` and you will see what is the structure of arry you have.

Comment: Hey, I tried changing it to that but it still displayed "NULL"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the full url eg:

```
<?php
$request_url = 'http://www.xboxgamercard.org/gamercard/test3/xbox.php';

$json = file_get_contents($request_url);
$data = json_decode($json, true);

//Example output
echo $data['gamertag']; //Crylics
echo $data['gamerscore']; //7492

/* Too access the recent_games key you will need
   to loop through it or access it like
*/
echo $data['recent_games'][1]['title']; //Call of Duty: WaW
?>
```

Comment: Thank you again! Im currently passing a GET variable in the url for xbox.php and index.php that is ?gamertag=crylcs so that it changes into     $request_url = 'http://www.xboxgamercard.org/gamercard/test3/xbox.php?gamertag=$gamertag'; but it doesnt seem to want to work?